# Problem in using jQuery datepicker in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to add Jquery date picker to TimeofCreation Form. I can't get the datepicker nor a select button. Please help in using date picker with jquery.

I want a date calendar to be appear when user clicks the form TimeofCreation.

Donor class code as follows

```
   public class Donor
   {
      [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FullName { get; set; }
     public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
     public DateTime TimeofCreation { get; set; }
     public string Emergency { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public BloodType BloodList    { get; set; }
     public string BagsNumber { get; set; }
     public DateTime LastTimeDonation { get; set; }

   }
```

My View code as follows.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeofCreation, htmlAttributes: new { 
    @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeofCreation, new { 
        htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeofCreation, "", new 
       { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        </div>


@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")


    <script type="text/javascript">
         <script>

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-60:+0"
    });
</script>
    </script>

}
```

Comment: Are you registering jQuery twice with your script tags and also the `@Scripts.Render()`?

Comment: yes may be I am not including jquery properly

Comment: Depending on what is going on in your script bundles that may be the problem. I would either remove the script tag or the calls to render those bundles.

Comment: pelase checked your browser console if any error found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here issue with you are not added `jquery-ui.css` file and other issue is you have uploaded multiple time `jquery` and `jquery-ui` js files. either use external script js file or use bundle.

and also order of your external script file is wrong it should be first `jquery` after use `jquery-ui` file

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

for example i used this and remove bundle .

and add your `jquery-ui.css` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

after that you can see your `datepicker`

after changes  code looks like

```
@model MVC5.Models.Donor
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeofCreation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeofCreation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeofCreation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

        </div>
    }

    @section Scripts {
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "-60:+0"
            });
        </script>
    }
```

[image]

i hope this should be helps you. let me know if require more information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to apply the datepicker to input[type=datetime] but I don't see that in the form-group.

Try linking it to the class like this:

`$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-60:+0"
});`

Comment: Still I can't see the datepicker.

Comment: I see that the out put of the Html.EditorFor will create an input[type=datetime] if the property in the model is DateTime. From this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/how-to-add-jquery-datepicker-in-mvc/